# ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged fires twice if hovering the dropdown

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a ComboBox in WinForms from which I am dragging items from the dropdown list onto a picturebox. If I drag an item straight out of the combo (right or left) the SelectedIndexChanged fires once. But if I happen to hover other items in the dropdown before the cursor leaves the combo the event fires twice.
I have tried almost every suggestion I could find to no avail. And, yes, the SelectedChangeCommitted works the same way.
Any ideas for a solution?

Comment: can you provide some code

Comment: Please include the relevant code and read up on [Minimal, Complete and  Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I had a similar problem that I thought was double events from changing a ComboBox. It turned out that I had the same function being called from two different events - SelectedIndexChanged and TextChanged. This is a reminder to check for this kind of silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Funny how it may help just to post a question! I found a usable workaround myself, like this:
First I added a global integer initially set to 0. Then, in the SelectionChangeCommitted I increment this by 1, and then ensure that code is run only when this value is 1. The problem was that wherever I reset this variable to zero (to be ready for the next drag operation), it  executed the code twice. 
The solution was to do the resetting only in the MouseClick event of the Combo as this occurs before the change-event. It will then be reset just when I attempt to start the next drag operation.

```
    int runonce = 0;

    private void cmbTags_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
    {
        runonce = 0;
    }

    private void cmbTags_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        runonce++;
        if (runonce == 1)
        {
            // My cmbTags_SelectionChangeCommitted-code
        }
    }
```